# Undefined Type Error "defaultView" with basic jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a basic resizing script using just raw jQuery v1.5.1 (Script below). For some reason it throws the following error and won't continue with running the script.

This is being tested with Chrome, Mac OSX

> Error
>   `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined`

Code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    /* Set initial #site width */   
    stretch_portal_content();
    $(window).resize( stretch_portal_content );
});


function stretch_portal_content() {
    alert($('#site').width());
    $('#left-container').width(
        $('#site').width()-150
    );

    if ($(window).height() > $('body').innerHeight()){
        $('#site').height(
            $(window).innerHeight()
        );
    }

}
```

Example HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="site">
        <div id="left-container">
            <div class="inner">
                <ul id="grid">
                    <li>Story 1</li>
                    <li>Story 2</li>
                    <li>Story 3</li>
                    <li>Story 4</li>
                    <li>Story 5</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right-container">
            <ul id="category-list">
                <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 7</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/core.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add example HTML so we can test it? Also what browsers does this error occur on?

Comment: I've determined it's something below or including the  "if" statement as on first run the code runs.

Comment: Ok, I know that's not the best way to word it. jQuery without plugins then?

Comment: Your HTML doesn't have a `</html>`.

Comment: You shouldn't drop the `{` like that. Not only is it ugly, but it's not standard Javascript and is not universally supported (to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: I do have the </html> I must have missed it off the post sorry, and I'll change the JS now. Thanks.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` is html5 and backward compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Inner Height Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/)

The issue is the innerHeight function is not applicable to the window object. Use height instead.